# How Is It Possible For a Group By To Return a Duplicate Key?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011

I received this exception in the error logs in our production environment:

```
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added
    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) 
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
```

The code has ran fine in all other environments as well as during unit testing.  I'm guessing there is some sort of multi-threading issue going on, but I don't know what it would be.  I would assume I would get some sort of Collection Modified exception, not a duplicate key exception.

This isn't the exact but a simpler example as to what is the code is actually doing:

### Edit 1

I've redfined how this is called and how the information is stored in hopes to answer some of the common questions in the comments...

```
public LotInfo CallSite(){
    return new LotInfo(new CarLot());
}

public class LotInfo {
    private Dictionary<int,int> SumOfMileageByYear { get; set; }

    public LotInfo(CarLot carLot)
    {
        SumOfMileageByYear = (from c in carLot.Cars
                group c by c.Year into carsByYear
                select new { Year = carsByYear.Key, Sum = carsByYear.Sum(c => c.Mileage) })
            .ToDictionary(c => c.Year, c => c.Sum);

    }
}


public class CarLot
{
    private IEnumerable<Car> _cars;
    public IEnumerable<Car> Cars
    {
        get
        {
            return _cars ?? (_cars = new List<Car>()
            {
                new Car(1984, "Dodge", "Rampage", 40696),
                new Car(2006, "Volkswagen", "Jetta", 42714),
                new Car(2009, "Nissan", "Versa", 53934),
                new Car(2005, "Lincoln", "Town Car", 62381),
                new Car(2008, "Ford", "Focus", 66072),
                new Car(2007, "Toyota", "Yaris", 68163),
                new Car(2009, "Hyundai", "Sonata", 71279),
                new Car(2006, "Ford", "F150", 73463),
                new Car(2005, "Mazda", "RX-8", 75000),
                new Car(2007, "Volkswagen", "Passat", 78490),
                new Car(2010, "Nissan", "Cube", 78505),
                new Car(2008, "Kia", "Sedona", 80874),
                new Car(2006, "Mitsubishi", "Eclipse", 81186),
                new Car(2008, "Ford", "Taurus", 83332),
                new Car(2008, "Pontiac", "G6", 85842),
            });
        }
        set
        {
            _cars = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Car
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Mileage { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }

    public Car(int year, string make, string model, int mileage)
    {
        Year = year;
        Make = make;
        Model = model;
        Mileage = mileage;
    }
}
```

The `Example` method is called, passing in a new instance of `CarLot`,  The property `Cars` is retrieved, which is lazy loaded, but returns a List implicitly cast as an IEnumerable.  Then the Group By method should return a single key with it's value.  All of  the deferred execution get's kicked off by the `ToDictionary()` call.

How is the Group By Linq Query producing a duplicate key without throwing an exception, causing the ToDicitionary call to fail?

### Edit 2

This is the actual code with zero context, the example basically provides the identical context as the actual code, with much better clarity.  I've added it just incase I missed something.

```
RepLeadCapTotalByRepRank = (from c in info.RepLeadCaps
                            group c by c.RepRank.Value into byRepTier
                            select new { RepTier = byRepTier.Key, Sum = byRepTier.Sum(v => v.Cap ?? 0) })
                           .ToDictionary(k => k.RepTier, v => v.Sum);
```

Comment: Your code works just fine to me.

Comment: Where do you assign the returned dictionary to anything? The constructor calls the method but throws the dictionary away.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek the code works just fine for me as well, but for some reason I'm getting the error in our production environment.

Comment: @TimSchmelter the actual code is assigning it to a `private Dictionary<int, int>` property of the class.

Comment: @Daryl Anything related to threads that happens to add the same key at the same time?

Comment: @Daryl are you storing the `Dictionary` somewhere where it could possibly be getting added to multiple times (e.g. session or static variable)?

Comment: @DStanley the error occurs on the ToDictionary() call.  I fail to see how where it is stored comes into play.

Comment: @lll See update.  The call is a non-static constructor and the object being passed in is being created in-line as well, so I don't think threading could affect it, but there are multiple threads processing this code.

Comment: @Daryl: even after your update your code works without a problem. So there must be an important difference to the real code. Is the LINQ query simplified?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I've posted the actual Linq Code.  The info.RepLeadCaps is just a lazy loaded call to Microsoft CRM 2011 for some BOs.  It does return a `List<repleadcap>`

Comment: @Daryl: i'm not familiar with MS CRM but maybe this link helps: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2808349

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter, but we are on Rollup 15, which I'm assuming has resolved whatever the issue with 12 would be, besides that, the the query has already completed without error.  The stack trace would be pointing to the lazy loaded property, not the ToDictionary() call itself.

Comment: What is the type of RepRank.Value ?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque RepRank is a CRM OptionSet, and RepRank.Value is an int.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I am seeing the same thing and this is the only other evidence that it happens online...

Comment: Nope @tigerswithguitars https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: guys, same issue here in 2021.
looks like multythreading issue.

Answer (score 2):

Change `.ToDictionary(c => c.Year, c => c.Sum);`  to

`.ToLookup(c => c.Year, c => c.Sum);`

Comment: Ok, but how can a `GroupBy` return multiple same keys? I assume OP don't want duplicate years.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think the real case is not what OP has posted. `An item with the same key has already been added` is clearly a dictionary.Insert exception and a Lookup can solve it.

Comment: I need to have it be unqiue per year, and even if I wanted that, how would that make sense?  For some reason some years have multiple sums?

Comment: @Daryl then post a **correct** example showing your problem. Your example works fine as said previously.

Comment: @L.B I'm guessing there is some sort of threading issue, but I'm not sure.  All I know is that it works fine when I unit test the code, as well as in all other environments, but in our prod environment it is failing at an 1-5% rate.